# sudo trash a file from swift to the user's Trash

Tags: swift, macos

The following code trashes the given files to the calling user's Trash.

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Darwin

struct swifterr: TextOutputStream {
  public static var stream = swifterr()
  mutating func write(_ string: String) { fputs(string, stderr) }
}

if (CommandLine.arguments.count < 2) {
  exit(2)
}

let manager: FileManager = FileManager.default

for item in CommandLine.arguments[1...] {
  do {
    let path: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: item)
    var destination: NSURL?

    try manager.trashItem(at: path, resultingItemURL: &destination)
  }
  catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription, to: &swifterr.stream)
    exit(1)
  }
}

exit(0)
```

If the user doesn't have permissions, she can retry using `sudo` - but this time they'll go to `root`'s Trash.

How can I avoid this, without hardcoding the user's Trash path? I looked up alternatives, and for instance [macos-trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/macos-trash) drops rights before running, which is not what I want.

Comment: If the user doesn’t have permission and you manage to move the files to the users trash then the use will not be allowed to empty the trash. Is this really what you want? Maybe it could work if when user runs as sudo then you first change ownership of the files but is that doable from code?

Comment: "macos-trash drops rights before running, which is not what I want" - may I ask why?

Comment: user must be able to trash root-owned files AND be able to restore them from trash. Finder allows this but it doesn't work when running in headless mode (eg. CI) because it needs graphical sudo